# How to control CSV import into Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, csv

When I open CSV files in Excel 2010 I get entire rows in cells, not distributed according comma separation.

How to control this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Open Excel and go to the `data tab - from text - select the file - import - delimited - next - comma - next - (settings) - finish`.

This will import your CSV file into Excel and will delimit it appropriately. Note if your CSV file uses something other than commas as separators, just choose that during the option selection phase.

---

Alternatively, if you've already opened it you can select the column and go to `data - text to columns - delimited - comma - finish` and that will break up your column across the row(s).

Answer (score 11):

You can do it using the import wizard, or you can do it by opening the file in a text editor and adding

```
sep=,
```

as the first line of the file.

Comment: Do you happen to know if there is a special string to tell excel what the decimal separator should be?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't.  I'd be interested to find out though. Let me know if you find anything.

Comment: How to do multiple "first line commands": Need to define separator and decimal e.g. "sep=\t  dec=." otherwise Excel is so smart and converts 1.2 (1,2) to a date ^^ ....

Comment: Yes, is this documented somewhere?